# android firebase storage file not found

Tags: android, firebase, download, http-status-code-404, storage

I am new at using Firebase and I am trying to simply download some images that I just uploaded in storage and populate in my listview, the problem is, the console says that the url from the current image doesn't exist (even existing).

here is my custom adapter where i download these images :

```
package studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui.adapters;

/**
 * Created by bruno on 09/05/2017.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui.R;
import studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui.helper.FirebaseConfig;

import studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui.helper.Grupo;

public class AllGroupsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Grupo> {

    private ArrayList<Grupo> grupos;
    private Context context;
    private StorageReference storage;

    public AllGroupsAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Grupo> objects) {
        super(c, 0, objects);
        this.grupos = objects;
        this.context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        storage = FirebaseConfig.getFirebaseStorage().child("groupImages");
        View view = null;

        // Verifica se a lista está vazia
        if( grupos != null ){

            // inicializar objeto para montagem da view
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            // Monta view a partir do xml
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.model_group, parent, false);

            // recupera elemento para exibição
            TextView nomeGrupo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nomeGrupo);
            TextView qtdMmebros = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qtd_membros);
            final ImageView imgGrupo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.groupImg);

            Grupo grupo = grupos.get( position );
            nomeGrupo.setText( grupo.getNome());
            qtdMmebros.setText( String.valueOf(grupo.getQtdMembros()) + " membros");
            // DOWNLOAD GROUP IMG FROM STORAGE

            storage.child(grupo.getNome()+".jpg");
            final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

            storage.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                    // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returns, use this as needed
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
                    System.out.println("bitmap venha "+bitmap);
                    imgGrupo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                }

            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle any errors
                    System.out.println("allgroups excessao "+exception);
                }
            });


        }

        return view;

    }
}
```

> > > here is the image erros of the cnsole

E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                                                                                   Object does not exist at location.
                                                                                    Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404

if someone knows what should I do, tks.

Comment: how do you initialise the StorageReference?

Comment: Can you share your StorageReference Code for better understanding your problem?

Comment: here is my storage reference     public static StorageReference getFirebaseStorage(){

        if(storage == null){
            storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("gs://ajudaqui-d58a0.appspot.com");

        }
        return storage;
    }